# Scrolling a view without lose data

Tags: android

I have an Scrollview in my app that has quite a large amount of data to load, all of them are TextViews that load an object attribute, but when i scroll the view, it sometimes load the object content to be shown, sometimes not. So what can i do to make this happen?

Here's the ViewHolder class(it's kinda ugly):
Something i forgot to mention, this class extends BaseAdapter, so, there's no activity

```
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtFaults;
    TextView txtA;
    TextView txtB;
    TextView txtC;
    TextView txtD;
    TextView txtE;
    TextView txtF;
    TextView txtG;
    TextView txtH;
    TextView txtI;
    TextView txtPFinal;
    TextView txtPart;
    TextView txtMF;
    TextView txtMP;
    TextView txtForm;
    TextView txtMN;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtMateria);
        holder.txtFaults = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtFaults);
        holder.txtA = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtA);
        holder.txtB = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtB);
        holder.txtC = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtC);
        holder.txtD = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtD);
        holder.txtE = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtE);
        holder.txtF = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtF);
        holder.txtG = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtG);
        holder.txtH = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtH);
        holder.txtI = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtI);
        holder.txtPFinal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPFinal);
        holder.txtPart = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPart);
        holder.txtMF = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMF);
        holder.txtMP = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMP);
        holder.txtForm = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtForm);
        holder.txtMN = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtMN);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Materia materia = list.get(position);
    holder.txtName.setText(materia.getMateria());
    holder.txtName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    holder.txtFaults.setText("Faults:"
            + Double.toString(materia.getFaltas()) + "%");

    holder.txtA.setText("A:" + Double.toString(materia.getA()));
    if (materia.getA() == 98.9)
        holder.txtA.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtB.setText("B:" + Double.toString(materia.getB()));
    if (materia.getB() == 98.9)
        holder.txtB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtC.setText("C:" + Double.toString(materia.getC()));
    if (materia.getC() == 98.9)
        holder.txtC.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtD.setText("D:" + Double.toString(materia.getD()));
    if (materia.getD() == 98.9)
        holder.txtD.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtE.setText("E:" + Double.toString(materia.getE()));
    if (materia.getE() == 98.9)
        holder.txtE.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtF.setText("F:" + Double.toString(materia.getF()));
    if (materia.getF() == 98.9)
        holder.txtF.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtG.setText("G:" + Double.toString(materia.getG()));
    if (materia.getG() == 98.9)
        holder.txtG.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtH.setText("H:" + Double.toString(materia.getH()));
    if (materia.getH() == 98.9)
        holder.txtH.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtI.setText("I:" + Double.toString(materia.getI()));
    if (materia.getI() == 98.9)
        holder.txtI.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtPFinal.setText("PF:" + Double.toString(materia.getPf()));
    if (materia.getPfinal() == 98.9)
        holder.txtPFinal.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtPart.setText("Partic:"
            + Double.toString(materia.getPartic()));
    if (materia.getPart() == 98.9)
        holder.txtPart.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtMF.setText("MF:" + Double.toString(materia.getMf()));
    if (materia.getMf() == 98.9)
        holder.txtMF.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtMP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (!materia.getForm().toLowerCase().contains("inform")) {
        holder.txtMP.setText("MP:"
                + String.format("%.2f", materia.getMP()));
        holder.txtMP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    holder.txtMN.setText("MN:LongClick to simulate");
    holder.txtMN.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    if (materia.getFormula().toLowerCase().contains("inform"))
        holder.txtMN
                .setText("Form not avaiable");

    holder.txtForm.setText("Form not informed");
    if (!materia.getFormula().toLowerCase().contains("inform"))
        holder.txtForm.setText("Form:" + materia.getForm());

    return convertView;
}
```

Tks

Comment: About what `ScrollView` are you talking? I see that you use an adapter so I assume that you use a `ListView` or `GridView`, so what are you doing with a `ScrollView`? I hope you're not combining this widgets.

Comment: yeah would help to post the xml as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realize that the lack of else on the logic were causing the trouble, thanks everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

implementing the

```
    onSavedInstanceState(Bundle bundle);
```

method should fix this problem.  You can find the information about it here 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Sorry, could you explain it a little more? When i scroll the view, only the getView() methood is called? So i have to implement this on the begin of getView()?

Comment: Its its own separate method that belongs to Activity.  If the Activity is brought out of focus or needs to re initialize for whatever reason it brings the Activity back to the state that you save in the Bundle parameter.  Android calls the method as needed so you dont have to do it manually.  I should have mentioned that you will also have to implement the onRestoreInstanceState method

Comment: Something i forgot to mention, this class extends BaseAdapter, so, there's no activity

Comment: ahhh ok, i was assuming you were working with an Activity thats my fault.  Disregard my answer